# Problem with colliding a player with a trigger and making the player go back to the main menu

Tags: collision

I made a trigger where the player collides and it goes to the main menu (scene 0) and it just wont work. I'm using unity with c#:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class SceneTransition : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string SceneToLoad;
    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player")) ;
        {
            SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneToLoad);
        }
    }
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

Is your game 3D or 2D? If its 3D, change the OnTriggerEnter2D to JUST OnTriggerEnter().
And check that the Is Trigger in the box collider (or whatever collider you're using) is checked. :)
You also put in a semicolon in the if(other...) so remove that. Semicolons aren't supposed to be put in to if statements

Answer (score 0):

There is very little detail in your question. Please check the following:
1. Is the collider attached to both the player and the trigger object?
2. What are their settings? Kinematic,etc ?
3. do you have a RigidBody attached to the player or the trigger object?
4. Is the SceneToLoad already registered in the Build?

These are the basics to make what you want. I suggest you revise the following topics:
1. Collision, Colliders and Rigidbody, especially search for Collision matrix
2. How SceneManagement works